# The phrase "Warp and woof"

Tags: grammar

If warps and woofs are threads of fabric, why does the phrase use them in singular?

Comment: Because they are "mass nouns".

Answer (score 2):

When using a primitive shuttle loom, the warp is one thread wound (vertically) around the frame.  The woof is one thread woven (horizontally) between the warp[s].  It is only after the fabric is removed from the loom that the two threads become many (by cutting the edges). (The woof is usually applied as a series of threads, but it acts like one long thread; likewise the warp, which may be different colors, but the ends are tied)